# Authors with multiple footnotes

Tags: formatting, footnotes, titles

Say I have an article. Under the title goes the name of three authors. The first author belongs to two organisations. The second belongs to one of the two from the first. And the last author belongs to a third organisation.

I considered either `\footnote` or `\thanks` but neither of them seem to allow me to tag several authors with the same footnote, and tag one author with several.

Here's an example:

> A.C. Clarke (a, b); F. Herbert (b); I. Asimov (c)
>
> (a): Stanford University
>
> (b): Yale University
>
> (c): Harvard University

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an easy way out is to just insert the appropriate `\thanks` where it is needed. The MWE below does this through `\specificthanks{<num>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}% Inserts a specific \thanks symbol
\makeatother
\title{My document}
\author{A.C.~Clarke\thanks{Stanford University}
  \textsuperscript{, \specificthanks{2}} \and
  F.~Herbert\thanks{Yale University}\label{yale-uni} \and
  I.~Asimov\thanks{Harvard University}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well except that the comma is too far to the left, right on top of the asterisk. I put a space before the comma in the superscript and that seems to make it somewhat better...

Comment: @Ozzah: I'm not obtaining that output. `\thanks` should place a `\footnotemark` immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [this handy trick by Anthony Liekens](http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences) to save and remember footnotes.

Here's a MWE [example](https://github.com/habi/latex/blob/master/multiple_affiliations.tex) I once prepared for myself...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
\footnote{#2}
\newcounter{#1}
\setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
\footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
}
\title{How to bowl properly}
\author{%
  The Dude\footremember{alley}{Holly Star Lanes Bowling Alley}%
  \and Walter Sobchak\footremember{trailer}{probably in a trailer park}%
  \and Jesus Quintana\footrecall{alley} \footnote{Mexico?}%
  \and Uli Kunkel\footrecall{trailer} \footnote{Germany?}%
  }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The whole example is taken from \href{http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences}{Anthony Liekens}\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will define a new counter each time a footnote is remembered. Seems a bit of a waste of counters. `\xdef`ing a macro should suffice.