# Authors with overlapping attributions-- siamltex

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to do the same thing that has been done in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/authors-with-multiple-affiliations), and in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/authors-with-multiple-footnotes), except now for the **siamltex document class**.  I have tried adapting the solutions presented in each example, with no success.

Here's an image of what I want, but in the article class, along with the code I used to get it.

[image: MWE_article_class]

```
\documentclass[final]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{Lame title}
\author{
    Francy-pants\thanks{Germany}
    \and
    Meow-face\thanks{USA}\textsuperscript{, \specificthanks{1}}
    \and
    Sizzly-pants\thanks{another part of the USA}
    \textsuperscript{, \specificthanks{3}}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

(I do not want whatever that weird artifact is with the comma and dagger on Meow-face, but that's not important at the moment.)

This is what happens when I change the class to siamltex:

[image: MWE_siamltex_class]

*Bonus points if you can figure out a solution that is independent of document classes.  (My multiple affiliations will follow me around for the next couple years, and I would hate to have to figure out a new hack for each new journal I apply to...)*

---

**Update**
I have a solution that mostly works:

```
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}

\title{Lame title}
\author{
    Francy-pants\thanks{Germany}
    \and
    Meow-face\footnotemark[1]\textsuperscript{ ,}\thanks{USA}
    \and
    Sizzly-pants\footnotemark[2]\textsuperscript{ ,}\thanks{another part of the USA}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

**The only complaint I have with this solution is that the order is not flexible.**  For example, if Meow-face is a super picky person and would like their USA affiliation to be listed before their German one, I wouldn't know how to interchange the asterisk and the dagger, since the `\footnotemark` and `\thanks` commands cannot be interchanged without errors.

Comment: i'm afraid a documentclass-independent solution isn't possible because the top matter structure of the input differs with different classes.  for example, for the ams document classes (although you may never submit to a journal that uses them), each author is entered separately, and the `\address` and `\thanks` elements are entered *outside* (although associated with) the scope of the `\author` entry.